# positive operator, projection, Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $T$ be a positive operator on a Hilbert space $H$. Let $P$ be a projection on $H$. Then, it is well-known that $PTP$ is also positive. My question is: whether $T\ge PTP$?

Comment: Yes, if $P$ is an orthogonal projection.

Comment: @TrialAndError: no, it's not.

Comment: @MartinArgerami : Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Let 
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix},\ \ P=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $T$ is positive (selfadjoint, with eigenvalues $0$ and $5$), but
$$
T-PTP=\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\2&4\end{bmatrix}
$$
is not positive (selfadjoint with eigenvalues $2\pm2\sqrt2$).